# Can someone explain this behaviour of the callbacks in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, callback

I tried out this code in nodejs :

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

console.log("-- line 1 --");

fs.ensureDir('./abc', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log("-- ensured --");
});

fs.copy("./sample", "./myFolder/samps", function (err) {
  if (err)  return console.error("sample to myFolder failed"); // sample is a file
  console.log("-- copied --");
});

fs.readdir("./myFolder", function (err, files) {
  if (err)  return console.error("-- read my dir --");
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    console.log(file);
  });
  console.log("-- my folder done --");
});

console.log("-- line 2 --");
```

The output I got for this is :

```
-- line 1 --
-- line 2 --
  ....
list of files -> doesn't include the newly copied "samps" file
  ....
-- my folder done --
-- ensured --
-- copied --
```

Now my question is shouldn't the order in which callbacks are executed be the order in which i wrote them - i.e, shouldn't it be like this - **ensured, copied, list of files and myFolder done**?

Now the next one which confuses me

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

console.log("-- line 1 --");

fs.ensureDir('./abc', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log("-- ensured --");
});

fs.copy("./sample", "./myFolder/samps", function (err) {
  if (err)  return console.error("sample to myFolder failed"); // sample is a file
  console.log("-- copied --");
});

fs.readdir("./", function (err, files) {
  if (err)  return console.error("-- read root dir --");
  files.forEach( function (file) {
    console.log(file);
  });
  console.log("-- root dir done --");
});

console.log("-- line 2 --");
```

Output for this :

```
-- line 1 --
-- line 2 --
-- ensured --
   ....
list of files and directories -> includes the newly created "abc" directory
   ....
-- root dir done --
-- copied --
```

What I don't understand is how come **ensured** is printed before **list of files** here, but not in the former case and why does **copied** always get printed at the end?

How come **abc** is showed when created in the list here but **samps** isn't included in the previous one?

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Because the callback fires when the execution is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look nodejs is an async language, It never waits for any input output on its single main thread.

So in the order of the line execution in your code will be like the order mentioned below.
1,2,3,4,5.
With the execution of 2,3,4 there will be a callback registered in the nodejs, which will be executed when the response of the respective functions is recieved. Now the order of function responses may depend on multiple factors (CPU usage, disk availability etc.), and will depend on the execution time required to perform that operation.

```
   1. console.log("-- line 1 --");

   2. fs.ensureDir('./abc', function (err) {
      if (!err) console.log("-- ensured --");
    });

   3. fs.copy("./sample", "./myFolder/samps", function (err) {
      if (err)  return console.error("sample to myFolder failed"); // sample is a file
      console.log("-- copied --");
    });

   4. fs.readdir("./myFolder", function (err, files) {
      if (err)  return console.error("-- read my dir --");
      files.forEach( function (file) {
        console.log(file);
      });
      console.log("-- my folder done --");
    });

   5. console.log("-- line 2 --");
```

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem requests (that do not originate from methods with the 'Sync' suffix) are executed in a thread pool, so all 3 of your requests will be executed in parallel. Because of this, you cannot make any assumptions about the order in which those requests are completed due to a variety of factors (e.g. disk state, OS scheduling, etc.).

If you need to ensure order, you need to chain the requests together using something like the third-party `async` module, Promises, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The **fs-extra** module, just like the core **fs** module provides functions in two flavors

- synchronous (e.g. **ensureDirSync**)
- asynchronous (e.g. **ensureDir**)

In synchronous case, execution thread blocks until a functions finishes, before proceeding to the next call. Hence, functions will be executed and finish in order they are called.
In asynchronous case, there is no way to control the order they finish execution and trigger the callback to log to console.

You're using the asynchronous, non-blocking version of the functions. Therefore order is not preserved.

Check out the documentation of the [**fs-extra** module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)

Answer (score 0):

Eaach of your calls to `fs`put the execution in a pool. You do not have access to that pool, nor can know how and when it will execute it.

What happen is this:

```
| Node.js thread                | Pool                              |
| ----------------------------- | --------------------------------- |
| import fs                     |                                   |
| Print "-- line 1 --"          |                                   |
| Start fs.ensureDir            | fs.ensureDir                      |
| Start fs.copy                 | fs.ensureDir, fs.copy             |
| Start fs.readdir              | fs.ensureDir, fs.copy, fs.readdir |
| Print "-- line 2 --"          | fs.ensureDir, fs.copy, fs.readdir |
|                               | fs.copy, fs.readdir               |
| Print "-- ensured --"         | fs.copy, fs.readdir               |
|                               | fs.copy                           |
| Print "-- copied --"          | fs.copy                           |
|                               |                                   |
| Print "-- root dir done --"   |                                   |
```

If you want your calls to happen in the order you expected, you must tell node.js to wait for the end of the execution of `fs` before continuing:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

console.log('-- line 1 --');

fs.ensureDir('./abc', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('-- ensured --');
    fs.copy('./sample', './myFolder/samps', function (err) {
        if (err)  return console.error('sample to myFolder failed'); // sample is a file
        console.log('-- copied --');
        fs.readdir('./', function (err, files) {
            if (err)  return console.error('-- read root dir --');
            files.forEach( function (file) {
                console.log(file);
            });
            console.log('-- root dir done --');
            console.log('-- line 2 --');
        });
    });
});
```

Or:

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async'),
    fs = require('fs-extra');

async.series([
    (callback) => {
        console.log('-- line 1 --');
        callback();
    },
    (callback) => {
        fs.ensureDir('./abc', function (err) {
            if (!err) console.log('-- ensured --');
            callback();
        });
    },
    (callback) => {
        fs.copy('./sample', './myFolder/samps', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                callback('sample to myFolder failed');
            }
            console.log('-- copied --');
            callback();
        });
    },
    (callback) => {
        fs.readdir('./', function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                callback('-- read root dir --');
            }
            files.forEach( function (file) {
                console.log(file);
            });
            console.log('-- root dir done --');
        });
    }
], (error) => {
    if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    console.log('-- line 2 --');
});
```

Comment: the last one shows an error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: Forgot to add `'use strict';`, that's all

Comment: Could you give more informations? The line for example?